# Filter python Dataframe by comparing string on column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have **rules** dataframe which has several columns:

```
col1 ... colx   s1       s2  
'a'      'g'    '123'   '123 school'
'b'      'g'    '456'   '123 school'
'a'      'r'    '123'   '456 school'
'd'      'g'    '456'   '456 school'
'a'      'g'    '123'   '123 school'
```

I need to filter out all rows where `'s1'` is not a substring from `'s2'`. The result would be:

```
col1 ... colx   s1       s2  
'a'      'g'    '123'   '123 school'
'd'      'g'    '456'   '456 school'
'a'      'g'    '123'   '123 school'
```

I need to do that in the fast way possible so I tried:

```
rules = rules[rules['s1'] in rules['s2']]
```

but it does not seem to work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use a comprehension and a boolean mask

```
df[[x in y for x, y in zip(df.s1, df.s2)]]

  col1 colx   s1          s2
0    a    g  123  123 school
3    d    g  456  456 school
4    a    g  123  123 school
```

---

You can also use `operator.contains` and `map`

```
from operator import contains

df[[*map(contains, df.s2, df.s1)]]

  col1 colx   s1          s2
0    a    g  123  123 school
3    d    g  456  456 school
4    a    g  123  123 school
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# compare columns row wise
boolean_selector = df.apply(lambda x: x['s1'] in x['s2'], axis=1)

# copy of the data-frame 
new_df = df[boolen_selector]

# view of the data-frame 
true_group = df.loc[boolean_selector]
```

As a one-liner;

```
df = df[df.apply(lambda x: x['s1'] in x['s2'], axis=1)]
```